# How can i access user control textfields in another class

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

i have a user control class named EmployeeInformation.aspx.cs with a Textfield txtRegistrationNo

```
 public partial class EmployeeInformation : System.Web.UI.UserControl
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public string TextRegistrationNo
    {
        get 
        {
           return txtRegistrationNo.Text;                
        }
    }

}
```

Now in another class named SeparationInfo.aspx.cs how can i access txtRegistrationNo field?

Comment: i tried this but got error

Comment: EmployeeInformation b = new EmployeeInformation();
obj.RegistrationNo = b.TextRegistrationNo;

Answer (score 0):

You have to access it through object of your custom control, suppose the instance of `EmployeeInformation` is `EmployeeInformation1`

```
string TextRegistrationNo = EmployeeInformation1.TextRegistrationNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EmployeeInformation  objEmployeeInfo = new EmployeeInformation();
string temp = objEmployeeInfo.TextRegistrationNo;
```